# React Rest Api Calls Pattern

Tags: reactjs, rest, design-patterns, react-redux

I'm trying to find a good pattern for api calls in React Web Developments. I want to a infrastructure for web apps, like a pipeline maybe. We use lots of components which makes api calls.  Most of them maybe use same apis. Most of the api calls might need to take valid token . According to these cases  I researched patterns. But obvioulsy I couldnt find anything. Redux base solutions convinced me a  little.

Now i have no project.  I'm trying to make a infrastructure to develop web apps frequently.

Can you give advice ?

Answer (score 0):

start with this:

- 1 page = 1 container component.
- Pass all api calls in containers components then diffuse the data to their children.
- When you will be a master in react, you will see that redux is bs, and you will do graphQl instead.